# better JSP server setup on windows?

Tags: windows, apache-2.2, tomcat

I'm currently running my jsp pages on a windows 2003 server, apache tomcat 5.5 setup.  My process involved is as follows:

1. make change to .java file
2. compile .java file
3. restart apache tomcat service
4. refresh browser
5. check c:\program files\apache software foundation\tomcat 5.5\logs

This is beyond cumbersome.  Is there a better development platform to develop jsp pages which makes life alot easier?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try resin from http://caucho.com ... besides many other features in the dev mode it recompiles changed java files on the fly - you just save the file in editor, refresh in the browser and observe tail -f of logs (even under windows).

Answer (score 0):

Use Ant or a similar tool to build your web application and package it into a war. Drop war in webapps folder.

Note that from time to time you will have to restart Tomcat due to PermGen leaks.

Packing your application as a war is neat and keeps things tidy and nice (i.e. if your Ant build is sane, your webapp will be easy to deploy for other people). However, this is slow for development. I would look for ways to run your webapp inside your IDE.